# Django CMS - customize the menu

Tags: html, css, django, menu

I am setting up DjangoCMS, and is using the `{% show_menu %}` in order to display the menu items created with the page creator.

I would like to customize this menu, so that it would look similar to [this](https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/ma5n11v0/).

In other words I would like the logo to be placed in the middle of the menu,
and it should scale responsively down to about 768px.

How can I render this logo into the ul li while still using `{% show_menu %}`tag.
Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/reference/navigation.html Here you look 4 show_menu template parameter